# Solve a partial differential equation with integral involved

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$
v\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial f(x,y,\theta)}{\partial x}+v\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial f(x,y,\theta)}{\partial y}
+a\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x,y,\theta)d\theta + b - f(x,y,\theta)\right) = -1
$$

$v, a, b$ are constants, $f$ is the unknown function to be solved, $x, y,\theta$ are arguments.

Can we get the analytical solution?